# Plus multiples variable (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a lot of variables(int) and want to add a number to all of it at once because i need it for a statement

here an example:

```
a, b, c, d = 3,5,6,7

if a + i == 10 or b + i == 10 or c + i == 10 or d + i == 10:
    #do something
```

Is there anyway i can compact this if statement

Comment: I assume you're looking to compact the expression  `a + i == 10 or b + i == 10 or c + i == 10 or d + i == 10` not what you have shown which would produce a SyntaxError.

Comment: The problem is `=` wihich is the assignment operator. Not what you want in a for loop; though `:=` is another story.

Comment: "I have a lot of variables" - You shouldn't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` (for python doc, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with generator comprehension:

```py
a, b, c, d = 3,5,6,7

i = 3
if any(x + i == 10 for x in (a, b, c, d)):
    print('hello')
```

Unless necessary, I would prefer to have the numbers in a single list, not in seperate variables.

```py
nums = [3, 5, 6, 7]

i = 3
if any(x + i == 10 for x in nums):
    print('hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a common denominator `i` that all if conditions share - why not calculate that subtracted value outside the if condition instead?

```py
a, b, c, d = 3,5,6,7

j = 10 - i

if a == j or b == j or c == j or d == j:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the numbers into a list or array and loop through a forloop to check, this would be helpful if you have a lot of numbers but with only 4 its not all that big of a deal